# Problem installing Cmdbuild (openmaint 2.0-3.1)

Tags: tomcat

I am trying to install openmaint 2.0-3.1a on windows server. I believe I have successfully installed:

1. JDK
2. Postgres (pgAdmin 4)
3. Apache Tomcat

I then

1. opened the tomcat at the website http://localhost:8080/manager/html and deployed Openmaint.war
2. In tomcat webpage, a new app with the Path /openmaint-2.0-3.1a showed up in the list, so I pressed 'start' from commands
3. When I press the path /openmaint-2.0-3.1a, The browser says “Waiting for localhost” and nothing ever shows up.

My database.conf is as follows:

```
#db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
#db.username=postgres
#db.password=admin
#db.admin.username=postgres
#db.admin.password=admin
```

MyContext.xml is as follows:

```
<Context displayName="CMDBuild" path="/cmdbuild">
<Resource name="jdbc/cmdbuild" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory"
defaultAutoCommit="true" maxIdle="10" maxTotal="80" maxWaitMillis="10000" />
</Context>'
```

My Database info is as follows:

**General-**

- Database: postgres
- Owner: postgres

**Connection-**

- Host name/address: localhost
- Port: 5432 Maint.
- Database: postgres
- Username: postgres

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are deploying a war file larger than configured in tomcat by default

1. Navigate to usr/share/tomcat9-admin/manager/WEB-INF/
2. Open web.xml with a text editor and change the max file size on line 57. I usually just add a zero. By default, it is set to 52428800 (ie 52M).
3. Restart tomcat with "sudo service tomcat9 restart" and you can now deploy your war file.

Answer (score 0):

to know the real issues please show us the result from openmaint.log or cmdbuild.log from tomcat logs folder. it maybe caused by java heap memory size that needs to run the apps. if allocated by default it may run very slow.

please refer to this [jvm memory allocation](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ars91/en/increasing-the-jvm-memory-allocation-and-thread-stack-size-609073221.html#JVMMemory-73425108)

and please uncomment the db setting to be like this

```
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
db.username=postgres
db.password=admin
#db.admin.username=postgres
#db.admin.password=admin
```

`